# Entity Framework 4 - Map Stored Proc that Returns Guid

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to map a stored proc in entity framework 4 that returns a guid scalar?  All I see is to have it return a collection or an int scalar.

My stored proc ends with a

```
select @id
```

where @id is the Guid I want back in code.

Answer (score 0):

No - function imports in EF4 always return collections that implement IEnumerable.  You can have it return a collection of guid scalars - but in your case, it would just be a collection with one object.  Does that work for you?

Brian

Comment: technically it appears they don't always return collections.  If you select return None when setting it up, it can have a return value of an int scalar, just not a guid.  I don't want to get a collection of guids back as I only need one so that seems sloppy.  I will go a different route.